# Using MonoTouch.CoreText to draw multi-line text

Tags: ios, uiview, xamarin.ios, core-text

I used that examples
  http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/graphics_and_drawing/core_text/draw_unicode_text_with_coretext/

[Using MonoTouch.CoreText to draw text fragments at specific coordinaates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21309082/using-monotouch-coretext-to-draw-text-fragments-at-specific-coordinaates#new-answer?newreg=6cd7d692895b4d0bbd4c2454cdf5adf0)

to draw a text line over UIView.

Now I need to extend it to draw multi-line text. Basically is simple. In the Draw() method I split the multi-line string Text on "\n" and than I call DrawTextLine() for any single line adding a newLineDY to Y.
The only problem is that any new line draw starts after the X draw end of the previous one:

aaa
   bbb
      ccc

How to avoid the X displacement? Can be reset? How? I try appling a negative DX for any line, but I don't know the right value to apply.

```
private const float newLineDY = 40;
public override void Draw()
    {
        string[] lines = Text.Split("\n".ToCharArray());
        float lx = X;
        float ly = Y;
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            DrawTextLine(line, lx, ly);
            //lx -= 100;        // negative DX
            ly += newLineDY;
        }
    }
    private void DrawTextLine(string text, float x, float y)
    {
        CGContext gctx = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
        gctx.SaveState();
        gctx.TranslateCTM(x, y);
        //gctx.TextPosition = new CGPoint(x, y);
        gctx.ScaleCTM(1, -1);
        //gctx.RotateCTM((float)Math.PI * 315 / 180);

        gctx.SetFillColor(UIColor.Black.CGColor);

        var attributedString = new NSAttributedString(text,
            new CTStringAttributes
            {
                ForegroundColorFromContext = true,
                Font = new CTFont("Arial", 24)
            });

        using (CTLine textLine = new CTLine(attributedString))
        {
            textLine.Draw(gctx);
        }
        gctx.RestoreState();
    }
```

Thaks!

Answer (score 1):

I have solved using attributedString.DrawString(new CGPoint(x, y)), a much simpler API, as suggested here

http://monotouch.2284126.n4.nabble.com/Using-MonoTouch-CoreText-to-draw-text-fragments-at-specific-coordinates-td4658531.html

So my code became:

```
    private const float newLineDY = 40;
    public override void Draw()
    {
        string[] lines = Text.Split("\n".ToCharArray());
        float lx = X;
        float ly = Y;
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            DrawTextLine(line, lx, ly);
            ly += newLineDY;
        }
    }
    private void DrawTextLine(string text, float x, float y)
    {
        NSAttributedString attributedString = new NSAttributedString(
            text,
            new CTStringAttributes
            {
                ForegroundColorFromContext = true,
                Font = new CTFont("Arial", 24)
            });
        attributedString.DrawString(new CGPoint(x, y));
    }
```